# Regex to split different codes from a long string of codes with no partitions

Tags: c#, regex

I have (essentially) a file of around 600,000 codes.

They look like this:

```
HJ43EKU2
```

When they're stored/loaded they look like this:

```
BJX4700QHJ43EKU2KU89EJKM
```

Each code is precisely 8 digits.

They are alpha numeric (a-Z,0-9) no accents or symbols.

So this works (for splitting code blocks):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]
```

But there's a problem as certain formats of codes aren't valid codes like this one:

```
MF93276H
```

The 7th digit can't be numeric.

This wouldn't be too bad except there's an exception as to if the 2nd digit of the code is `N` (or later in the alphabet) then this then makes the code valid again.

How do I implement some logic to the REGEX as so that it takes into account the 'exception' to a rule re-validating a code?

Comment: what is the expected result for the above posted `BJX4700QHJ43EKU2KU89EJKM` ?

Comment: Is it in PHP? What is the language flavor?

Comment: `HJ43EKU2` and
`KU89EJKM`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew C#

Comment: By the way, if you would make your Regex object use case-insensitive matching, you could reduce `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to `[a-z0-9]`, shortening your regex pattern while maintaining its readability...

Comment: Also, here a possible solution not relying on capture groups, but using alternation: `(?i)(?:[a-z0-9][n-z][a-z0-9]{6}|[a-z0-9]{6}[a-z][a-z0-9])` (it already includes case-insensitive matching modifier)

Comment: By the way, the description of the code you want to extract from the string would also apply to `JX4700QH` in your example string above. You might want to think about how you can define your expected results in a **formal manner** that would exclude false positives. (Possibly such a false positive could potentially overlap with a real code you want to extract, thus preventing the regex from matching the real code). Just giving one or two examples is unfortunately not sufficient to reliably determine for any case what you want to extract and what you don't want to extract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you may use a known technique using a capturing group and later evaluating it:

```
var rx = "[a-zA-Z0-9]N[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]|([a-zA-Z0-9]{6}[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9])|[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]";
var results = Regex.Matches("BJX4700QHJ43EKU2KU89EJKM", rx)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Where(m => !m.Groups[1].Success)
            .Select(z => z.Value);
foreach (var s in results)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/6WsZAu)

**Regex details**

- `[a-zA-Z0-9]N[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]` - valid code pattern with the second char equal to `N`
- `|` - or
- `([a-zA-Z0-9]{6}[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9])` - Group 1 (if matched, discard it): invalid code pattern
- `|` - or
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]` - valid code pattern.

**NOTE**: If *N (or later in the alphabet)* means that if the second char is `O`, `P` .. `Z`, you need to replace `N` in the first alternative with `[N-Z]`.

**Code details**

- `.Where(m => !m.Groups[1].Success)` - if Group 1 did not match, the match is a valid code, so grab those only
- `.Select(z => z.Value)` - keeps the whole match object value text only in the result.

Comment: @Sanguine Actually, it was a bit hard to follow the logic in your question, please  pay attention to my notes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use alternative construct:

```
var x = @"HJ43EKU2";
var match =
    Regex.Match(x, @"(?i)[a-z0-9](?([n-z])[a-z0-9]{7}|[a-z0-9]{5}[a-z][a-z0-9])");
var code = match.Value;
```

• `(?i)` Make search case-insensitive

• `(?(n-z))` Zero-width assert which checks whether the 2-nd char is `N` or "more"

• `[a-z0-9]{7}` If 2-nd char **is** `N` or more, then allow the 7-th char to be numeric

• `[a-z0-9]{5}[a-z][a-z0-9]` If 2-nd char **is not** `N` or more, *disallow* the 7-th char to be numeric

Comment: I guess you could do without zero-width lookahead. Simply make `[n-z]` match, followed by 6 `[a-z0-9]`. Still an upvote for the simplicity of the regex pattern...

Comment: No, nobody downvoted. I just accidentally unvoted (clicked the upvote button again, because i am twitchy and don't pay attention). My bad, remedied now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot recommend *against* this strongly enough, but .NET actually supports conditional groups, so you *could* do:

```
var pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9](?:(?<n>N)|[a-zA-Z0-9-[nN]])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}(?(n)[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]";
Regex.IsMatch("MF93276H") // false
Regex.IsMatch("MN93276H") // true
```